# How to get value from a .geojson that was converted into a geopandas GeoDataFrame?

Tags: geojson, geopandas, overpass-api

I got the following .geojson file from Overpass API:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "generator": "overpass-ide",
  "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.",
  "timestamp": "2022-07-18T07:57:39Z",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature"
...
```

I converted this simply with `gdf = geopandas.read_file(filename)` into a GeoDataFrame object. This all worked great.

The GeoDataFrame object now contains all elements that were listed inside of "features" within the .geojson.

But now I wondered if there is any way for me to access the value for "timestamp" on this GeoDataFrame object? Or does the GeoDataFrame object not even contain this key/value-pair anymore?

`gdf["timestamp"]` does not work.

I could use the json-library like shown below, but then I would have to load the entire file again which seems like a huge waste of resources.

```
import json
f = open('filename.geojson', encoding="utf8")
data = json.load(f)
timestamp = data["timestamp"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: neither pandas nor geopandas support custom metadata fields. the underlying driver used by geopandas to read geojson objects, fiona, does support metadata, so you could read the file with fiona and then send the data to geopandas. However, extracting a small amount of metadata with the json library is pretty fast compared to parsing geometrycollections, so you might find it's not too bad to do the two-stage read as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Michael. 
I must admit that I have not really a frame of reference for judging if doing something a certain way is acceptable or not regarding the runtime. I think my algorithm & data structures class just scared me too much so that I am always worried about this kind of stuff. But if you say, that it should be okay to just use the json-library, then I will do so. 
If you want you can post your comment as answer, so that I can accept it if that is how it's done around here :)